# Multiple IPMI message bridging interpretations

Tags: local-area-network, ipmi, bmc

Let's say I would like to send `Get Device Id` command from `LAN` channel to `IPMB` channel via `BMC` with `message tracking`, I need to go through those steps:

1. Encapsulate `Get Device Id` command in `Send Message` command
2. Send `Send Message` command from `LAN` to `BMC` providing required data like target `IPMB` address, all those `NetFn`s, `LUN`s and most relevant in this case: *request-unique* `Sequence Number` and `message tracking` parameter bit set

Here starts my confusion.. because I saw 2 different solutions how `BMC` handle this kind of requests:

`A` **Response on `Get Device Id` comes back in the `Send Message` response**

`B` **Separate `Send Message` and `IPMB` responses**

, which turns out dependent on `BMC` producer.

So I need some experts knowledge:

Is this how `IPMI` standard stands for, that `BMC` implementation can provide `A` and/or `B`?
Or this is misguided interpretation of `BMC` producers?

In my opinion and the way I understand `IPMI 2.0 spec`, only `B` solution is one and only compatible flow how it should work as confirmed in `6.13.4 Bridged Request Example`:

> When a request message is bridged to another channel by encapsulating it in a *Send Message* command (from a source channel other than the system interface), the BMC immediately returns a response to the *Send Message* command itself. Meanwhile, the request is extracted from the *Send Message* command and forwarded to the specified target channel.

`IPMI 2.0 spec` even provide example description:

> For example, suppose a *Get Device ID* command has been encapsulated request in *Send Message* command directed to the IPMB from a LAN channel. The BMC will immediately send a response to the *Send Message* command back on LAN. The BMC will extract the encapsulated *Get Device ID* message content and format it as a *Get Device ID* request for IPMB. The target device on IPMB responds with a *Get Device ID* response message in IPMB format. The BMC takes the tracking information that was stored when the *Send Message* command was issued, and uses it to create a *Get Device ID* response in LAN format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of FreeIPMI.  Of all the motherboards I've worked with, "B" has always been the supported implementation.  I have personally never seen an implementation of "A".  I would consider the "A" implementation minimally "non-standard" (in the sense even if a legal wording was found in the IPMI specification for "A", industry has standardized on "B").

Unsure of your end goal, but if you are developing a product, I would be confident saying "B" will work on most IPMI servers.  If you have the ability to speak to the "A" vendor, I would definitely push them to implement "B".

Comment: I realize that my goal was unclear, but all I needed is opinion like yours. Thank you.